# Spring service class contains too many finder methods

Tags: java, spring, service, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring framework and Spring Data JPA to develop an application. Below are one of the repository interface and service class.

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>
    User findByName(String name);
    User findByEmail(String email);
}

public class DefaultUserService implements UserService {
    @Inject protected UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public User getUserById(Long id) {
        return userRepo.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByName(String name) {
        return userRepo.findByName(name);
    }

    @Override
    public User getUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepo.findByEmail(email);
    }
}
```

As stated by many experts, service layer design should be coarse grained and focused on application operations. Looking at the service class above, I believe that is not a good design as it directly expose all finder methods from the repository. Since all 3 service methods above are returning the same object type (User), I would want to expose only one finder method instead of three that able to encapsulate all finder logic.

```
public class DefaultUserService implements UserService {
    @Inject protected UserRepository userRepo;

    // what would be the arguments and logic for this method.
    @Override
    public User getUser() {
    }
}
```

I appreciate if anyone can point me the solution on how to solve this design issue?

Comment: you may check out `DetachedCriteria` in Hibernate, then you can pass it to `getUser()`. But I think it's not as good as your original design.

Answer (score 1):

I think the design is not so bad, I mean I was seeing that kind of approach several times, in fact you have several finder methods but each one use different property to obtain the User, if you want to make a service method which encapsulate the logic to retrieve the user I would suggest something like this.

```
public class DefaultUserService implements UserService {
    @Inject protected UserRepository userRepo;

    enum UserFindEnum{
        ID, EMAIL, NAME;
    }

    public User getUser(UserFindEnum e, Object obj){
        switch(e.ordinal()){
            case 0:
                return userRepo.findOne(obj);
            case 1:
                return userRepo.findByName(obj);
            case 2:
                return userRepo.findByEmail(obj);
            default:
              break;
        }
    }
}
```

I mean you need to know which property you will use to find the User so at least one parameter need to be sent to the service layer so `getUser()` it is not enough. Probably using some kind of logic as above you will have only one service method and needed logic within it.

Comment: i think you need to add one more param for id, name, email.. like: `public User getUser(UserFindEnum e, Object obj)`

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Based on the hints above I prefer to expose two methods which are getUser(Long id) and getUser(UserFinderCriteria finderCriteria). UserFinderCriteria contains the UserFinderEnum (BY_NAME, BY_EMAIL) and builder methods such as buildNameFinder(String name) and buildEmailFinder(String email).

Comment: Sure if you find my answer useful don't forget to upvote the answer =), that will help me a lot. thanks.